# Exception in parsing json object in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am making connection to an url inorder to retrieve json data and then later parsing it.
Here is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    int responsecode = -1;
    try {
        URL HeadingUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=10"); // Create a URL object
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) HeadingUrl.openConnection();   //we would make a connection object so as to connect to the url
        connection.connect();   // connection to the required url & also may throw IO exception

        responsecode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (responsecode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); // catching the data in an input stream as it can be of any type
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); //reading the inputstream byte by byte
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength(); // creating size so as to store data which will be character by character
            char[] charArray = new char[contentLength]; //character array to store data
            reader.read(charArray); // reading from inputStream and storing in char array
            String responseData = new String(charArray); //converting char into string


            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseData);
            String status = jsonResponse.getString("status"); // for a test
            Log.v(TAG, status); // for a test purpose

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("posts");
            for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject individualPost = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = individualPost.getString("title");
                Log.v(TAG, "title" + i + ":" + " loop ");

            }

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unsuccesful Code is :" + responsecode);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught ", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught ", e);
    }
    return "Code : " + responsecode;
}
```

After getting the json data in responseData as a string i am not able to parse it, and it is catching the exception (3rd catch block) ,can you tell what is the problem and how to overcome this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: logcat message :
10-03 03:24:54.692    3039-3183/? E/com.example.prashant.blogreader.MainListActivity﹕ Exception caught
    org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 4059 of {"status":"ok","count":12,"count_total":2084,"pages":174,"posts":[{"id":25575,"url":"http:\/.....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with reading the input stream .try my function to  read the input stream.

```
public static  String getTextFromStream(InputStream inputstream)throws IOException{

    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line="";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }

    return total.toString();
}
```

use it like that :

```
String responseData=getTextFromStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: but I am getting the required data in responseData..i confirmed it from debugging...problem is in parsing i think

Comment: can you post the response ?